# Converting JSON list (from an API) into a python dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I'm working on a REST API assignment in uni which *should* be simple, but I've become stuck and have been going round in circles for hours.

I've been tasked with writing python code which 'consumes' JSON data from an API. Scope and Easy enough, right? The scope is up to me, so I have decided to keep it simple.

1. Get data JSON from: [here](https://api.openbrewerydb.org/v1/breweries?by_city=miami&per_page=5)
2. Parse it into a python list.
3. Iterate through the list to display the key value pairs for multiple objects.

I thought `json.loads()` would parse my JSON data into a Python dictionary so that I could use `items()` in a for loop to produce the key value pairs, but I can only achieve the following:

I can do this in a manner using `enumerate()` on the list, but it does not format the results the way I would like.

I've used `.items()` in a for loop with `my_dict = {"name": "Alice", "age": 30, "city": "New York"}` successfully in another file - no problems at all there! The JSON response from the url is wrapped i and I thought it would be far easier to convert it than it is!

I feel I'm missing something extremely obvious here put cannot put my finger on it.

Could someone offer any advice? Code is below.

```
import json
import requests

url = "https://api.openbrewerydb.org/v1/breweries?by_city=miami&per_page=3"
response = requests.get(url)
print("\nhttp status code: ",  response.status_code, "- ", response.reason)

json_data = json.loads(response.text)
print("JSON data type:", type(json_data))

print('\nResults using index method')
json_dict = json_data[0]
for key, value in json_dict.items():
print(key, ": ", value,)

print('\nResults using enumerate method')
for key, value in enumerate(json_data):
print("{} : {} ".format(key, value))
```

Comment: "but no luck": can you be more specific?

Comment: Updated. Thanks for pointing it out. I can either output a single object in the format I want, or multiple objects in a hard to read format.

Comment: Wow, thanks to both of you @Ricardo Bucco - not only did your answers work, but I actually understood them too! How would I go about storing those dictionary values as well as printing them? –

Comment: And and @Sohan JS too - only one tag per comment!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `json` module to parse the response. Just use the functionalities of `requests`:

```
json_data = requests.get(url).json()
```

To print the response you could, for example, do this:

```
for json_dict in json_data:  # Iterate through the list of JSON objects
    for key, value in json_dict.items():  # Display the key value pairs for each object
        print(key, ": ", value)
```

Answer (score -1):

The JSON response from the given API is a list of dictionaries. Therefore, when you do `json_data[0]`, you are accessing the first dictionary in the list.

Try this! This modified code iterates through the list of breweries and then iterates through each brewery's key-value pairs. The `enumerate` method is used to display the index along with the brewery data in a formatted manner

```
import json
import requests

url = "https://api.openbrewerydb.org/v1/breweries?by_city=miami&per_page=3"
response = requests.get(url)
print("\nhttp status code: ", response.status_code, "- ", response.reason)

json_data = json.loads(response.text)
print("JSON data type:", type(json_data))

print('\nResults using index method')
for brewery in json_data:
    for key, value in brewery.items():
        print(key, ": ", value)

print('\nResults using enumerate method')
for index, brewery in enumerate(json_data):
    print(f"Brewery {index + 1}: {brewery}")
```